# Unexpected value "steps" in yaml template

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I don't understand how the have one file like this hierarchy is carried over into templates because I just get errors:

```
Pipeline
  Stage A
    Job 1
      Step 1.1
```

Consider this yml file:

```
trigger:
  - master

stages:
  - stage: build
    displayName: "Run Build"
    jobs:
      - template: someTemplate.yml
```

My template looks sort of like (tried putting jobs as the first hierarchy as well):

```
pool:
  name: "Azure Pipelines"
  vmImage: "windows-2019"

steps:
  - task: myTask
    inputs: ...
```

I believe I follow the right structure but I don't understand how the hierarchy follows to the template.

I get:

```
/generate-release-notes.yml (Line: 3, Col: 1): Unexpected value 'pool'
/generate-release-notes.yml (Line: 7, Col: 1): Unexpected value 'steps'
```

Comment: Can you share the whole yaml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your YAML template sample, you are defining the steps template.

In this case, you cannot define the pool in the template because the pool cannot be defined at the step level of yaml.

On the other hand, since you defined the steps yaml template, you also need to reference this template in the step level in the main yaml.

To solve your issue, you need to modify your template YAML to define the job level YAML template.

Here is an example:

someTemplate.yml

```
jobs:
  - job: NameA
    pool:
     name: "Azure Pipelines"
     vmImage: "windows-2019"
    steps:
      - script: echo 1
```

azure-pipelines.yml

```
trigger:
  - master


stages:
  - stage: build
    displayName: "Run Build"
    jobs:
      - template: someTemplate.yml
```

Comment: I figured it out in the end, identical to your solution.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use a `steps` template as a `job` template.

```
jobs:
  - template: someTemplate.yml
```

is expecting `someTemplate.yml` to contain a `jobs:` block with a job or series of jobs in it. You're giving it steps.

Comment: I've tried adding "jobs" and "job" to the someTemplate but I get an error whatever I put. If I do "jobs:" then I get "unexpected jobs", and if I do "- job:" or "job:" I get unexpected sequence/job. Can you nudge me further in the right direction?